# Indexes for combined time and location data

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgis, postgresql-performance

I have a multi-TB table with geolocation data for a certain item id and timestamp.

It is partitioned by time with a partition for every month (~500GB), and clustered (including the partitions) on the  item id and time index.

```
CREATE TABLE data(
  itemid integer not null,
  ts timestamp not null,
  pos geometry(Point,4326) not null,
  otherdata varchar not null -- Stand in for other columns
) partition by range(ts);

CREATE INDEX data_cluster ON data (itemid, ts);
CREATE INDEX data_brin ON data USING brin (itemid, ts, pos) with (pages_per_range = 8);

CREATE TABLE data_201901 PARTITION OF data
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-01-01') TO ('2019-02-01');

CREATE TABLE data_201902 PARTITION OF data
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-02-01') TO ('2019-03-01');
```

This performs very well for our most common queries, where the data of one or a small number of items is queried for a range of time (several hours to days).

A secondary type of query we would like to do is all items in or near a location in a certain time range. Our intention is that the brin index can be used for this since `(item_id,ts)` is highly correlated with `pos`.

Something like this:

```
select itemid, ts, pos, otherdata from data
where ts >= '2019-02-02 00:00:00' AND ts < '2019-02-03 14:00:00'
AND st_within(pos,  st_setsrid(
                st_geomfromgeojson('{"coordinates":"coordinates":[[[-74.05059814453125,40.6920928987952],[-73.92013549804688,40.6920928987952],[-73.92013549804688,40.79405848578324],[-74.05059814453125,40.79405848578324],[-74.05059814453125,40.6920928987952]]],"type": "Polygon"}'),
                4326
              ) :: geometry)
```

We see however that the normal btree index is used for this, and the queries take too long to be useful (multiple minutes to over an hour)

What is a way to enable these queries?

- Is there a combined time and geospatial index?
- Is there something that can be done to make the brin index being used?
- Is the best way partitioning on a smaller timeframe like a day and creating a geo index for each partition?

**edit** on request of eppesuig, an example execution plan of the above query:

```
 Gather  (cost=1000.70..71744000.35 rows=1933 width=44) (actual time=164868.705..1227645.633 rows=65701 loops=1)
   Output: data_201902.itemid, data_201902.ts, data_201902.pos, data_201902.otherdata
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=18009528 read=12157953 dirtied=246522 written=253711
   I/O Timings: read=2117627.130 write=2645.225
   ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.70..71742807.05 rows=805 width=44) (actual time=164838.218..1227566.491 rows=21900 loops=3)
         Buffers: shared hit=18009528 read=12157953 dirtied=246522 written=253711
         I/O Timings: read=2117627.130 write=2645.225
         Worker 0: actual time=164823.732..1227566.470 rows=23522 loops=1
           Buffers: shared hit=6011928 read=4078259 dirtied=81890 written=85133
           I/O Timings: read=709048.959 write=873.459
         Worker 1: actual time=164824.015..1227556.922 rows=22578 loops=1
           Buffers: shared hit=5974480 read=4022282 dirtied=82190 written=84063
           I/O Timings: read=702613.742 write=856.134
         ->  Parallel Index Scan using data_201902_cluster on public.data_201902  (cost=0.70..71742803.02 rows=805 width=44) (actual time=164838.216..1227552.572 rows=21900 loops=3)
               Output: data_201902.itemid, data_201902.ts, data_201902.pos
               Index Cond: ((data_201902.ts >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (data_201902.ts < '2019-02-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Filter: (('010...4540'::geometry, data_201902.pos))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 40950205
               Buffers: shared hit=18009528 read=12157953 dirtied=246522 written=253711
               I/O Timings: read=2117627.130 write=2645.225
               Worker 0: actual time=164823.730..1227551.115 rows=23522 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=6011928 read=4078259 dirtied=81890 written=85133
                 I/O Timings: read=709048.959 write=873.459
               Worker 1: actual time=164824.013..1227542.124 rows=22578 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=5974480 read=4022282 dirtied=82190 written=84063
                 I/O Timings: read=702613.742 write=856.134
 Planning Time: 5.442 ms
 Execution Time: 1227669.990 ms
```

Comment: Your query needs the index by `(ts, pos)` (or backward - analyse plan or test).

Comment: Could you show the plan executed by postgresql?

Comment: @Akina postgis `geometry` columns cannot be part of a btree index

Comment: @eppesuig Added it to the post

Comment: Your query uses "data_201902_cluster", but you don't show the definition of an index by that name.

Comment: @jjanes It's the `(itemid, ts)` index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a multi-column index on spatial and time data.

```
create extension btree_gist;
create index on data using gist (ts, pos);
```

With GiST, you generally want the column which is used more-selectively in the query to be first in the index.  I suspect that that is "ts", but I don't know for sure.  You might want to try it both ways.

A multicolumn BRIN index is basically the same thing as multiple independent single-column BRIN indexes.  If your data is clustered on "item_id", then the "ts" column in the BRIN index is unlikely to be useful, unless "item_id" and "ts" are highly correlated with each other.

> Is the best way partitioning on a smaller timeframe like a day and creating a geo index for each partition?

Maybe, but that would not be my first resort.  I'd try the `USING GIST (ts,pos)` index first.  And it looks like you haven't even tried a `USING GIST (pos)` on your existing partitioning yet.  I wouldn't go around changing the partitioning without first trying what you already have.

Comment: `btree_gist` looks useful, thanks, i'll try that. `USING GIST (pos)` was tried, but did not give enough performance in most queries because points are highly concentrated.